# Quartz Schedular hangs or does not respond on jboss startup if the missfired triggers are huge

Tags: jboss, quartz-scheduler

I have a jboss server and we are using Quartz as a scheduling service.

On normal start up of jboss, it initializes the Quartz in the end.

But while starting the jboss if number of misfired triggers are more than say 2000 it halts at "handling 2000 misfired triggers".

My thread pool size is set to 5. Even though all triggers are in a Queue and processing in the batch of 5, my application server does not get started. If i hit the url i get the service not available. Is there any way to change the above behavior. I have have misfired instruction as "Fire Now".